# How to change rules at runtime , when deployed with Mule app ? i.e. How to make rules dynamic in mule app?

Tags: mule, drools

I configured rules inside mule project as described in mule specs, Using BPM rules activity. 
But I am not able to change rules in runtime (i.e. without redeploying the app.)

Mule Documentation says

Use Rules if 
"The business logic needs to be maintained by people who don’t (or shouldn’t) have access to the application itself (to recompile/redeploy it)"

So it should be possible to change rules without redeploying the mule-app.

I found that after deployment of mule-app with rules , the drl files are present in below location 
"mule-standalone-3.7.0\apps\projectName\classes"
But if I modify the rules in these drl file and save them, still the changes do not reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
If you are running the server on linux, you could select an xml file like a flow, and execute the 'touch' command on the file. With this method, the app will do a hot redeployment. By the way I still have not tested it.

Comment: Using server on windows . But I tried changing the main flow file ,by adding few spaces at some places where it does not matter in flow file and saved. But  still the changes I did in drl files to rules , did not reflect in service output.

Comment: Now, changing the main flow file and saving it, is making my app to restart. And even the changes in drl file do reflect after it. May be I was doing something wrong before. But in this way , it still requires restart of the application, for changes in the rules to come into effect. And for making business people(non-technical people) to be able to change the rule, redeployment should not be required.

Comment: * for making business people(non-technical people) to be able to change the rule without the involvement of techinal people, restarting of app should not be required.Other solutions are still welcomed.  @Alex: Thanks for replying ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how drools works with Mule app, but to update rules at runtime you can use KieScanner API's. With these KieScanner API's we can load latest version of rules without redeploy or restart. I have tried with KieScanner API's in standalone code and with Web application it works fine, I am expecting it will work woth mule as well